# Cannot access element by key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a Items List I try to pass a `key`-prop like this:

```
 var feedItems = this.props.items.map(function(item){
        return <FeedItem key={item.key} 
                         title={item.title} 
                         description={item.description}
                         voteCount={item.voteCount}
                         onVote={this.props.onVote}/>
    }.bind(this));
```

Somehow this **won't work** In the **FeedItem** I cannot access the key like that:

```
this.props.key == undefined
```

I saw it like that in a VideoTutorial, that is why Im wondering why it won`t work? How can I access the key of an item? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`key` is a special property to handle [dynamic children update](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children). It was once accessible from `props` but then was moved out starting from v 0.12.

You should use another name so that it won't interfere with how React is updating the dom. Ideally you would have that `key` property to uniquely identify dom nodes within a containing parent and another key (with another name) property for your own use.